# What is the correlation in kafka stream/table, globalktable, borkers and partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am studying kafka streams, table, globalktable etc. Now I am confusing about that.

What exactly is GlobalKTable?

But overall if I have a topic with N-partitions, and one kafka stream, after I send some data on the topic how much stream (partition?) will I have? 
I made some tries and I notice that the match is 1:1. But what if I make topic replicated over different brokers?
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your questions as you have them listed here.

A GlobalKTable has all partitions available in each instance of your Kafka Streams application.  But a KTable is partitioned over all of the instances of your application.  In other words, all instances of your Kafka Streams application have access to all records in the GlobalKTable; hence it used for more static data and is used more for lookup records in joins.

As for a topic with N-partitions, if you have one Kafka Streams application, it will consume and work with all records from the input topic.  If you were to spin up another instance of your streams application, then each application would process half of the number of partitions, giving you higher throughput due to the parallelization of the work.

For example, if you have input topic A with four partitions and one Kafka Streams application, then the single application processes all records.  But if you were to launch two instances of the same Kafka Streams application, then each instance will process records from 2 partitions, the workload is split across all running instances with the same application-id.

Topics are replicated across different brokers by default in Kafka, with 3 being the default level of replication.  A replication level of 3 means the records for a given partition are stored on the lead broker for that partition and two other follower brokers (assuming a three-node broker cluster).

Hope this clears things up some.

-Bill